# Can I run two lines INTO a single condensate pump?

Tags: pump, dehumidifier

Just moved into our first new (old) home and am quickly learning the "joys of homeownership"! In the basement, there is a Little Giant VCMA-15ULST condensate pump attached via PVC for air conditioning.  This pump appears to have two more input plugs.  I need to get a dehumidifier for the basement and am wondering if I can input a line from a dehumidifier into this same pump, or if I need to buy a separate pump for the dehumidifier?  Still haven't had to turn on the AC yet because we're still cool temps.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually whole-house AC can make about 3L/hour in humid conditions, and condensate pumps have rates in the range of 5 L/min. So adding another dehumidifier is perfectly handleable by the pump.

Comment: Could you elaborate? For example, are you saying that it would be OK for the OP to run two lines into a single condensate pump?

Comment: Usually whole-house AC can make about 3L/hour in humid conditions, and a pump have a rate in the range of 5 L/min. So adding another dehumidifier is perfectly handlable by the pump.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited your comment into your answer (we don't want answers to depend on the comments).